# Short form for Gradle dependsOn, mustRunAfter

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle

Is there a more compact way for this gradle snippet:

```
A.dependsOn X
B.dependsOn X
C.dependsOn X
D.mustRunAfter X
E.mustRunAfter X
F.mustRunAfter X
```

I am looking for something short, sweet and clever, like:

```
[A,B,C].dependsOn X
[A,B,C].dependsOn [X,Y]
[D,E,F].mustRunAfter X
```

(which, does not work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code does the job:

```
['A'..'F', 'X', 'Y']
  .flatten()
  .each { n ->
    task "$n" {
      doLast {
        println "$n"
      }
    }
  }

[A, B, C]*.dependsOn X, Y
[D, E, F]*.mustRunAfter X
```

It uses groovy's [spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator).

Comment: Thanks! Still wish that Gradle developers had provided something shorter...